# How to generate x-ray based graph using Highcharts Javascript

Tags: javascript, graph, highcharts

How to generate x-ray-based graphs using Highcharts Javascript.

For reference please follow below reference image

[image]

Comment: Hi! To create that kind of chart, you will need to prepare the data in the format that Highcharts expects and use the line chart. You will find some examples of the line chart demos here: https://www.highcharts.com/demo/line-basic You can freely customize the chart design and style using the Highcharts API.

Comment: You need to use Timeline charts with "Plotlines" options enabled.

**[link](https://jsfiddle.net/49j63q0k/)**